# NotSerializableException thrown when accessing currentBuild.changeSets in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline, changeset

I'm very new in Jenkins Pipeline and groovy script so please bear with me. I am trying to setup a Jenkins pipeline where I can access the modified (Git) files in the current build. I do this with the following line of code:

```
   def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
```

This will work fine if there is no file change in the current build but will throw the exception java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList otherwise.

If I remove or comment out the line "def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets the build will succeed with or without change

I search online about this issue but all I found is that this would happen if I try to access currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets without the marking it @NonCPS but I am only accessing currentBuild.changeSets here

I have stripped down my Jenkinsfile to the bare minimum as follows and confirm that the line "def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets is the culprit. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

```
@Library('EzeUtils')
pipeline {
    agent {label 'Windows'}

    stages {
        stage('Intial Setup')
        {            
            steps {
                echo "workspace directory: ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                echo bat(returnStdout:true,script:'set')
                script
                {
                    notify.notifyBitbucket('START','OMS',GIT_COMMIT)
                    gitList = gitInfo.getGitInfo()
                    GIT_COMMIT = gitList[0]
                    GIT_AUTHOR = gitList[1]
                    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL = gitList[2]
                    GIT_COMMIT_COMMENT = gitList[3]
                    GIT_BRANCH = "${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
                    echo "GIT_COMMIT:" + GIT_COMMIT
                    echo "GIT_AUTHOR:" + GIT_AUTHOR
                    echo "GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL:" + GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
                    echo "GIT_COMMIT_COMMENT:" + GIT_COMMIT_COMMENT
                    echo "GIT_BRANCH:" + GIT_BRANCH
                    def version = "1.2.3." + env.BUILD_NUMBER
                    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
                    // gitInfo.gitTag(version)

                    notify.notifyBitbucket('INPROGRESS','OMS',GIT_COMMIT)
                    utils.updateProductInfo(env.BUILD_NUMBER)
                    version = utils.readProductInfo()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post
    {
        always
        {
            println "--------------------- Run always ---------------------"        
        }
        success
        {
            println ("SUCCESSFUL: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}] author: ${GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL} commit: ${GIT_COMMIT}' (${env.BUILD_URL}) ")
            script
            {
                notify.notifyBitbucket('SUCCESS','OMS',GIT_COMMIT)
            }
        }

        failure
        {
            println ("FAILED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}] author: ${GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL} commit: ${GIT_COMMIT} ${GIT_COMMIT_COMMENT}' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
            script
            {
                echo "Print::::::${GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL}"
                notify.buildFailedEmail(GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL)
                notify.notifyBitbucket('FAILED','OMS',GIT_COMMIT)
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? In general to cover something with `@NonCPS` you need to encapsulate it in a function.

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS

@NonCPS
def myMethod() {
    return currentBuild.changeSets... //get what you need from change sets here
}

...

    def changeLogSets = myMethod()
```

You need to work on Serializable objects outside of NonCPS, that's exactly what your exception says `java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList`

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm still getting java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList even if I replaced "def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets" with a method call as you suggested. Furthermore, according to this  https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals, the, you should only need the @NonCPS annotation if you are accessing currentBuild.rawBuild

Comment: Sorry, yes of course. ChangeSet itself is non implementing serializable, hence you won't be able to use it outside NonCPS annotated functions. Corrected my answer.