# What commits are pulled by Jenkins in the build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins has information about commits included in a particular build. I know this because Jenkins displays this (see the screenshot below).

**How can I pull the information about commits included in the build during the CI execution?**

This information is required to check what folders have files modified and, as a result, to determine what actions Jenkins should execute.

Thanks!

P.S. To achieve this in CI jobs for PRs, I use git command:

```
git rev-parse github/master
```

It returns the last commit made in master before current branch was branched off (to make it work I add 'github' remote). Obviously, it can't work in the 'master' branch itself. So I'm thinking, maybe Jenkins has some built-in information that I can use? Or some Jenkins plugins can help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a bunch of links, though I could not find any until I figured the keyword to google for it.

**1st of all**, there is a DevOps version of StackOverflow:
https://devops.stackexchange.com/
It might have more people active that can help with Jenkins related questions

**2nd**, the idea is to use jenkins variable currentBuild and further iterated through:

- currentBuild.previousBuild
- build.changeSets
- items in the build
- commit hashes are in the item.commitId

Links that helped me to figure out the solution:

- [What commits are pulled by Jenkins in the build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69386105/what-commits-are-pulled-by-jenkins-in-the-build)
- https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/get-all-change-logs-of-since-last-successful-build-in-jenkins-pipeline?newreg=52d68c7ced584340988071cc72440ca1
- https://blog.csdn.net/liurizhou/article/details/88236397
- [NotSerializableException thrown when accessing currentBuild.changeSets in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57154064/notserializableexception-thrown-when-accessing-currentbuild-changesets-in-jenkin)
- https://gitter.im/jenkinsci/jenkins - public chat with jenkins community, not super active, but still helpful.

IMPORTANT NOTES:

1. Because of how Groovy works in Jenkins you need to put this logic into a separate function and add "@NonCPS" attribute to it
2. All variables inside need to be prefixed by 'def' (even though my prettier told me this is not required), without this you will have "java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList" errors.

Hope this will help someone as well!